# Old Source Code into New Repository

Tags: git, revision

Quick question:

I've run into a little issue, where I just need some insight into what I should do with some code I have.

I have one repository, in two locations.  The "older" code is located in `/originalcode` and the new **checked-out** code is in `/just-checked-out`.

Here's the problem:

Over the past few months, I've been updating code in `/originalcode` and there have been several new updated to the code (I kinda got lazy with my repository and never commited new changes).

I'm wanting to merge all my changes into the code repository using the new protocol (I changed from git+ssh to smart http).

Is this as easy as changing the "remote" url in the git config file.  I just want to make sure that I'm following proper guidelines and don't overlook something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all remote settings, you can fiddle with `.git/config` as [Greg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893/greg-hewgill) [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704304/git-old-source-code-into-new-repository/4704310#4704310),
... or you should have a look to **[`git remote` command](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html)**: that will achieve the same effect, but with much more options (`set-head`, `set-branches`, ...), without having to look at [`git config`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) man page.

Comment: Thanks, the remote command seems more "one off" (which is what I need) :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change the URL in `.git/config` and that will change where the remote URL points to. There's no other configuration that needs to be changed.